# How to reduce this binary polynomial to the sum of squares in various ways

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I can convert this binary polynomial to the sum of the squares of multiple polynomials using the following method:

```
5 x^2 + 2 x y - 14 x + 2 y^2 - 10 y + 17 //. 
  (a : _ : 1)*s_Symbol^2 + (b : _ : 1)*s_ + rest__ :> 
     a (s + b/(2 a))^2 - b^2/(4 a) + rest
```

But I found that the following results also meet the requirements:

```
(x - y + 1)^2 + (2 x + y - 4)^2 // Expand
1/2 (x + 2 y - 5)^2 + 9/2 (x - 1)^2 // Expand
9/17 (y - 2 x)^2 + 1/17 (7 x + 5 y + 17)^2 // Expand
1/5 (5 x + y - 7)^2 + 9/5 (y - 2)^2 // Expand
```

I want to find all polynomial sums of squares as much as possible.

Comment: Is there another word for "square results"? I am not familiar with the concept, but from your code it seems that you are looking to express the polynomial as a sum of squares. Is that right?

Comment: @MarcoB Yes, I have updated the problem statement. I want to find all possible combinations.

Comment: Quick comment/apology: MSE is indicating that I gave this a downvote two days ago (I only just noticed). Apparently I cannot change it unless/until the question is edited. I wanted to say that if I did this it was an inadvertent mouse click (or maybe an intended upvote), and the question is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 12 solutions

```
lhs = 5 x^2 + 2 x y - 14 x + 2 y^2 - 10 y + 17
rhs = (a x + b y + c)^2 + (p x + q y + r)^2
SolveAlways[lhs == rhs, {x, y}]
```

When some **concise integer solutions** are desired, we can proceed as follows

```
A=2;
z=Solve[!Eliminate[!(A lhs==rhs),{x,y}],Integers];
Table[Factor[(a x+b y+c)^2/A/.i]+Factor[(p x+q y+r)^2/A/.i,{i,z}]//DeleteDuplicates
```

$$\frac{9}{2} (x-1)^2+\frac{1}{2} (x+2 y-5)^2 $$

```
A=5;
z=Solve[!Eliminate[!(A lhs==rhs),{x,y}],Integers];
Table[Factor[(a x+b y+c)^2/A/.i]+Factor[(p x+q y+r)^2/A/.i],{i,z}]//DeleteDuplicates
```

$$\frac{9}{5} (y-2)^2+\frac{1}{5} (5 x+y-7)^2 \\
 \frac{1}{5} (4 x-y-2)^2+\frac{9}{5} (x+y-3)^2$$

```
A=10;
z=Solve[!Eliminate[!(A lhs==rhs),{x,y}],Integers];
Table[Factor[(a x+b y+c)^2/A/.i]+Factor[(p x+q y+r)^2/A/.i],{i,z}]//DeleteDuplicates
```

$$\frac{1}{10} (7+x-4 y)^2+\frac{1}{10} (7 x+2 y-11)^2 \\
 \frac{1}{10} (5 x-2 y-1)^2+\frac{1}{10} (5 x+4 y-13)^2$$

```
A=13;
z=Solve[!Eliminate[!(A lhs==rhs),{x,y}],Integers];
Table[Factor[(a x+b y+c)^2/A/.i]+Factor[(p x+q y+r)^2/A/.i],{i,z}]//DeleteDuplicates
```

$$ \frac{1}{13} (8 x+y-10)^2+\frac{1}{13} (x+5 y-11)^2 \\
 \frac{1}{13} (7 x-y-5)^2+\frac{1}{13} (4 x+5 y-14)^2$$

```
A=Prime[10000000];
z=Solve[!Eliminate[!(A lhs==rhs),{x,y}],Integers];
Table[Factor[(a x+b y+c)^2/A/.i]+Factor[(p x+q y+r)^2/A/.i],{i,z}]//DeleteDuplicates
```

$$\frac{(28015+5263 x-16639 y)^2}{179424673}+\frac{(29486 x+9055 y-47596)^2}{179424673} \\
 \frac{(20431 x-9055 y-2321)^2}{179424673}+\frac{(21902 x+16639 y-55180)^2}{179424673}$$

Comment: But how do you turn the result into a concise form like  `1/5 (5 x + y - 7)^2 + 9/5 (y - 2)^2`?

Comment: @PleaseCorrectGrammarMistakes Three things: 1) It is a bit arbitrary what "concise" means (hard to define mathematically), 2) It was not asked in the OP to find a "concise" form, 3) what if "concise" form is not always possible, for instance for continuous family solutions?

Comment: `(rhs /. #) & /@ SolveAlways[lhs == rhs, {x, y}]` will give you a list of polynomials closer to the 'concise form' you want e.g `rhs /. SolveAlways[lhs == rhs, {x, y}][[1]]` gives `(5/Sqrt[2] - (53 x)/(17 Sqrt[2]) - (8 Sqrt[2] y)/
   17)^2 + (-(3/Sqrt[2]) - (9 x)/(17 Sqrt[2]) + (15 Sqrt[2] y)/17)^2`

Comment: @PleaseCorrectGrammarMistakes See update for concise solutions

Answer (score 4):

There is a general way to obtain different representations as a sum of two squares. It is somewhat related to responses both by @yarchik and by @chyanog.

First compute the symmetric matrix that gives this polynomial.

```
vec = {x, y, 1};
symmat = {{a, b, c}, {b, d, e}, {c, e, f}};
poly = 5 x^2 + 2 x y - 14 x + 2 y^2 - 10 y + 17;

mat2 = 
 symmat /. SolveAlways[vec.symmat.vec == poly, {x, y}][[1]]

(* Out[329]= {{5, 1, -7}, {1, 2, -5}, {-7, -5, 17}} *)
```

Now diagonalize it by finding the eigensystem. Normalize the eigenvectors to have unit length, so that the eigenvector matrix is orthogonal.

```
{vals, vecs} = Eigensystem[mat2];
vecs2 = Map[Simplify[#/Sqrt[#.#]] &, vecs];
```

We can get a somewhat lengthy sum of squares representation right away. This is pretty much a (modified) Cholesky decomposition where we use the first two eigenvectors and the square roots of the first two eigenvalues (the third eigenvalue is zero and the corresponding eigenvector is thus a null vector). I numericize to save on length.

In[333]:=
newvec = (vec.Transpose[vecs2[[1 ;; 2]]])*Sqrt[vals[[1 ;; 2]]];
newvec // Expand // N

(* Out[334]= {4.10853 - 1.81399 x - 1.14727 y,
0.346358 + 1.30745 x - 0.826905 y} *)

In[335]:= N[newvec.newvec] // Expand

(* Out[335]= 17. - 14. x + 5. x^2 - 10. y + 2. x y + 2. y^2 *)

So this dot product is one such SOS representation.

```
In[337]:= N[newvec.newvec]

(* Out[337]= 
2.51317 (0.218482 + 0.824736 x - 0.521609 y)^2 + 
 21.4868 (0.88634 - 0.391336 x - 0.247502 y)^2 *)
```

A way to obtain others is to parametrize linear combinations of the two eigenvectors, rescaled by the square roots of the corresponding eigenvalues.

```
newvecs = {{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {-Sin[t], Cos[t]}}.(Sqrt[vals[[1 ;; 2]]]*
     vecs2[[1 ;; 2]]).vec;
```

So we get different SOS representations by selecting different values for `t` in the interval from 0 to `2 Pi`. We show that this works for `t=Pi/3` below.

newvecs.newvecs /. t -> Pi/3. // Expand // N

Out[339]= 17. - 14. x + 5. x^2 - 10. y + 2. x y + 2. y^2

Finding "nice" values of the parameter `t`, that give rise to sums of squares with rational coefficients, is another matter entirely. So this is really just a partial answer. I will show one "nice" SOS though. Start by extracting coefficients for one of the vectors that give the SOS.

```
coeffs = 
 FullSimplify[Flatten[Normal[CoefficientArrays[newvecs[[1]], {x, y}]]]]

(* Out[352]= {1/2 Sqrt[34 + 53 Sqrt[2/5]] Cos[t] + 
  1/2 Sqrt[34 - 53 Sqrt[2/5]] Sin[t], 
 1/2 (-Sqrt[10 + Sqrt[10]] Cos[t] + 
    Sqrt[10 - Sqrt[10]] Sin[t]), -Sqrt[1 + 1/Sqrt[10]] Cos[t] - 
  Sqrt[1 - 1/Sqrt[10]] Sin[t]} *)
```

Set the last coefficient to zero and solve for `t`.

```
soln = Solve[Last[coeffs] == 0 && 0 <= t <= Pi, t][[1]]

(* Out[367]= {t -> 
  2 ArcTan[2 Sqrt[5/(10 + Sqrt[10])] + Sqrt[(10 - Sqrt[10])/(
     10 + Sqrt[10])]]} *)
```

Now use this substitution on those vectors.

```
simp = FullSimplify[newvecs /. soln]

(* Out[368]= {(3 (-1 + x))/Sqrt[2], (-5 + x + 2 y)/Sqrt[2]} *)
```

Here is the resulting SOS representation.

```
simp.simp

(* Out[369]= 9/2 (-1 + x)^2 + 1/2 (-5 + x + 2 y)^2 *)
```

Offhand I do not know what to solve for in general in order to obtain nice representations.

Answer (score 3):

Easy to know

$\frac{((6 x-3 y) \cos (t)+(17-7 x-5 y) \sin (t))^2}{17}+\frac{((17-7 x-5 y) \cos (t)-(6 x-3 y) \sin (t))^2}{17}=5 x^2+2 x y-14 x+2 y^2-10 y+17$

[image]
we can proceed as follows

```
Tuples[Range[0, 20], 2].{1, I} // Arg // DeleteDuplicates // Rest // 
  Map[Factor /@ (1/17 ((6 x - 3 y) Cos[#] + (17 - 7 x - 5 y) Sin[#])^2 + 
    1/17 ((17 - 7 x - 5 y) Cos[#] - (6 x - 3 y) Sin[#])^2) &] // 
   TakeSmallestBy[First /* Denominator, 10] // Column // TraditionalForm
```

Output:

> [image]

Get the decomposition in terms of **sin** and **cos**

```
lhs = 5 x^2 + 2 x y - 14 x + 2 y^2 - 10 y + 17;
rhs = (√5 Cos[α] x + √2 Cos[β] y + √17 Cos[γ])^2 + (√5 Sin[α] x + √2 Sin[β] y + √17 Sin[γ])^2;
sol = Solve[CoefficientRules[lhs - rhs, {x, y}][[All, 2]] == 0, {α, β}];
sol = Simplify[sol,TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, PowerExpand}] /. C[_] -> 0
Simplify /@ (rhs /. sol[[1]])
```

Output:

> $\frac{1}{17} (3 \sin (\gamma ) (2 x-y)+\cos (\gamma ) (7 x+5 y-17))^2+\frac{1}{17} (\sin (\gamma ) (-7 x-5 y+17)+\cos (\gamma ) (6 x-3 y))^2$

Comment: How did you get the decomposition in terms of `Sin` and `Cos`? Is it unique?