# How to refine polynomial which has a constraint condition to perfect square?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

The expression : `1 + 4 p2^4 + 4 p2^2 (-1 + p1^2 - p3^2) - 4 p3^2 (-1 + p1^2 + p3^2)` has a constraint condition: `(p0^2 + p1^2 + p2^2 + p3^2) == 1` (How to add this constraint condition to the expression? And you can use `p3^2+p1^2=1-p0^2-p2^2` to get the result I want manually), but I can't use Mathematica to let the expression to be the form: see the picture [image]

Comment: `l0^2` is letter-el or 10^2 = 100, I suspect it is the former, else what you are trying to get will never materialize. Are there 4 variables in total? Could you at least use 'p' instead of 'l' as it easier to read? Do you want to maximise, minimize or just simplify?

Comment: `Simplify[expr,constraint]` should do it. I know because I have checked. Please press F1 for Simplify.

Comment: @Syed - what version are you using? With v12.3.1 on a Mac, `Simplify[expr, constraint]` does not produce the requested form.

Comment: `1 + 4 p2^4 + 4 p2^2 (-1 + p1^2 - p3^2) - 4 p3^2 (-1 + p1^2 + p3^2)` is produced by Simplify[expr, constraint] and expected expression is `1 - 4 p2^2 + 4 p1^2 p2^2 + 4 p2^4 + 4 p0^2 p3^2` on expansion. On subtracting one from the other and simplifying again, the result is zero. I haven't worked on collecting coefficients to make it look exactly as posed.

Comment: Do you require that particular form? Or will any sum of squares suffice? If the latter, could check methods shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/223942/how-to-reduce-this-binary-polynomial-to-the-sum-of-squares-in-various-ways) or [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133141/expressing-a-polynomial-as-a-sum-of-squares). Could first preprocess by homogenizing and reducing the first polynomial by the (implied) second one.

Answer (score 1):

Reduce says, you cannot transform the first expression into the second valid for all variables.

```
f1 = 1 + 4 p2^4 + 4 p2^2 (-1 + p1^2 - p3^2) - 
4 p3^2 (-1 + p1^2 + p3^2);
cond = (p0^2 + p1^2 + p2^2 + p3^2) == 1;
f2 = (1 - 2 l2^2)^2 + 4 (l0^2 l3^2 + l1^2 l2^2);
red1 = Reduce[
ForAll[{p0, p1, p2, p3}, cond, f1 == f2], {l0, l1, l2, l3}]
(*   False   *)
```

Comment: Why? Is there any other condition need?